# How to optimize regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I have many URLs like this one:

`/url?q=http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX&sa=U&ei=oijvVNKSF4W8ygOowILgAw&ved=0CBQQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHD3R0UX-Wfnl3D-LKn__SbHU4tZQ`.

In final I want to have just clear URL like this one:

`http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX`

I did it with 2 operations `preg_match()`

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++){
    $link_without_url[].= preg_replace('~/url\?q=~', '', $links[$i]);
}
for($j = 0; $j < count($link_without_url); $j++){
    $site_name = preg_replace('~&.*~', '', $link_without_url[$j]);
    $site = file_get_contents($site_name);
    preg_match_all('~<a.*?href="([^"]+)".*?>(.*?)</a>~s', $site, $match);
    $links = $match[1];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++){
        echo $i.'))'.$site_name.' '.$links[$i].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Where $links is array of my start URL.
Is it possible to do using just one `preg_match()` or something else function for regular expression?

Comment: try `explode()` : `pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0];`
pass "&" as first arg to `explode()`

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two lines

```
$link_without_url[].= preg_replace('~/url\?q=~', '', $links[$i]);
$site_name = preg_replace('~&.*~', '', $link_without_url[$j]);
```

with:

```
$site_name = preg_replace('~^/url\?q=([^&]++).*~', '$1', $links[$i]);
```

We capture the url `([^&]++)` in the first backreference and replace the whole line with this backreference.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. It's exactly what I wanted.